# Complex RxJS iterator only visible rows

Tags: javascript, scroll, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

We have over 500 rows from list on each request, sometimes it's 10 and sometimes its huge.

I want to take that array and only show what is visible on the screen and hide everything else, but has user scroll down it will display other rows and hide previous ones.

This is bit complex, I was watching RxJS video and Netflix did similar. I'm not sure what functions to use to have this effect.

https://gist.github.com/iBasit/8ceef1db9de945a37559 Netflix example.

Our code:

```
Observable.fromArray([0,1,2,.....500]).subscribe(row => show(row));
```

Comment: You need something like https://github.com/stackfull/angular-virtual-scroll. I haven't seen anything for Angular2 yet (doesn't mean much, I'm using it since about 1,5 months).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a couple articles (like [this one](http://qiita.com/kimagure/items/d29ed7b7bdaaf6977b9a)) and various demos on how to do this "virtual scrolling thing", but basically what you need is either static row heights or the ability to determine if a given row will be visible on the screen (`Row#isRowVisible` in that gist you linked).

Then the easiest way to display rows afterwards is to absolutely position them such that you either multiply the index by your static row height OR calculate where the row should display somehow.

[This](https://github.com/justinwoo/react-rxjs-scroll/blob/master/src/index.js) is a pretty rough demo of how to do this in React, but the ideas are very similar (you might be able to just copy paste the RxJS code from that or my Cycle.js example). I'd encourage you to try making it yourself though.

Also, 500 items really shouldn't be much of a problem for angular2 (it's really fast), unless you have a ton of elements in each row.

Comment: well 250 items took really fast to fetch from api (less then second), but then it starting parsing which took more then 5 or more seconds, unless i reduce to `take(20)` which then shows within second or two.

Comment: what if I don't know my row height or if row height is different every time? like some places row hight will be 100px and sometime 500px.. or sometimes just one line 20px.  how can I calculate these kind of rows?

Comment: If you don't have static dimensions for your rows, there are no methods out there that can help you.

Comment: can't we get height dynamically? `$(div).height();` would that not work?